# How to set the active class on progress bubbles in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the active class on my progress bubbles with a click of a button on my web page

```
    <div ng-show="step.one" class="progress-bubble-container">
        <ul class="progress-bubbles">
            <li id="gs1" class="active">1</li>
            <li id="gs2">2</li>
            <li id="gs3">3</li>
            <li id="gs4">4</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

I have four steps and each step pass in the  step number to my javascript method

```
<a  ng-click="SubmitRegistration(1)" class="btn btn-primary main-btn pull-right next-step">Register</a>
```

I tried something like this:

```
$scope.setNavigation = function(num) {
  var nextStep;
  nextStep = num + 1;
  return $("#gs" + nextStep).addClass('active');
};
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This question is two open ended. It is also an AngularJS code sample. Are you sure this is a JavaScript code problem or an Angular problem? When you say "This is not working" How is this so? What did you expect? Why do you feel it is not working? Why do you feel your doing something wrong? Try expanding on the specifics of the problem, perhaps offer a sample in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with simple counter

your html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="step"></li>
    <li class="step"></li>
    <li class="step"></li>
</ul>

<div class="stepContent"></div>
<div class="stepContent"></div>
<div class="stepContent"></div>
```

your js:

```
 var steps = $(".step"),
     cntns = $(".stepContent"),
     current = 0;

     //default step activation
     setStep(current);

     steps.click(function(e){

         current = $(this).index();
         setStep(current);
     });


     function setStep(num){
          step.removeClass("isActive").eq(num).addClass("isActive");
          cntns.removeClass("isActive").eq(num).addClass("isActive");
     }
```